# Wake On Lan not working

Tags: networking, wakeonlan

I have been trying to get Wake On Lan to work on my Ubuntu server (14.04.1 LTS), which I have configured as a home NAS box. I have followed several tutorials to try to get this working, but for some reason, which I can't trace, it is not working.

The system is an old (4-5 year old) shuttle pc system (Shuttle SN78SH7), amd64 cpu (AMD Athlon 64 X2 7550).

Steps taken so far

1. I have set WoL on my BIOS
2. I have enabled WoL (method g) on eth0
3. I have added a script so that eth0 stays as g on startup
4. I can confirm that the green and orange lights on the network card are on

If I use ethtool, I can see the following, which I believe means it is configured as expected.

```
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
```

I am using [wolcmd](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-for-apple-mac.aspx) (from a mac), to send the magic packet, to the MAC address, IP address, and subnet specified in `ifconfig eth0` (to port 9).

I am not sure what the next steps should be to try to resolve the problem.

**UPDATE**

I can confirm that WoL does indeed work sometimes if I suspend (`pm-suspend`), but does not if I use (`halt -p` or `shutdown -h now`). Suspend seems to be really unstable, so using that is not likely to be a good answer for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a Linux-specific issue. Wake-on-lan is implemented by the motherboard and network card, not the operating system. Try upgrading your motherboard BIOS if you can, and also note from [the SN78SH7 manual](http://download.shuttle.eu/Mirror/XPC/SN78SH7/Manual/MANUAL.ZIP):

> **WOL(PME#) From Soft-Off** If this item sets to Enable, the system power
>   will be turned on when the LAN port receives an incoming signal. You
>   have to connect the fax/modem to the mainboard Wake On LAN connector
>   for this feature to work. The choice: Enabled or Disabled.
>
> **MAC Resume from S4/S5** This item allows you to enable/disable the MAC
>   Resume from S4/S5. The choice: Disabled or Enabled.

You need to enable both of these options. In particular, *MAC Resume from S4/S5* is needed to power up a shut down PC.

Comment: perfect, thank you. I had WOL(PME#) set to enabled, but the MAC Resume from S4/S5 disabled. Switching this to enabled means I can now `shutdown -h now` and resume remotely with the magic packet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. First, install `ethtool`:

   ```
   sudo apt install ethtool
   ```
2. For testing and temporarily enabling WoL:

   ```
   ethtool -s eth0 wol g
   ```

   Replace `eth0` with the name of your network interface.
3. To enable WoL permanently edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the next line (from Debian 6 "Squeeze" and above):

   ```
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
        ethernet-wol g
   ```